# find only quantities with a decimal SQL

Tags: sql

Looking to find qty where only decimals exist. I get a `varchar` conversion error when executing my simple query.

Example that doesn't work:

```
SELECT qty
WHERE qty between '%.000001' and '%.9999999'
```

Tried to convert `varchar` to numeric with no luck.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `FLOOR` ([mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_floor) / [sql server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178531.aspx)) function to compare the rounded value with the original one:

```
SELECT qty WHERE qty != FLOOR(qty)
```

Answer (score 0):

In Sql Server, How about:

```
... WHERE ISNUMERIC([item cost]) = 1
```

or

```
... WHERE NOT TRY_PARSE([item cost] AS NUMERIC(19,2)) IS NULL
```